# how to place bootstrap model at right bottom of screen in react js?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using inline CSS to place model at right bottom of the screen but it is not working perfectly

```
<div className="modal fade " style={{ width:'30%',position:'fixed',bottom:0,right:0,margin:0}} id="updateCategory" tabIndex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true" >
```

it gives me following output
[image: output]

even if remove all css properties above except `width:'30%'` result is same.

but if I use following style it works

```
<div className="modal fade " style={{ width:'30%',bottom: 0,marginTop:260,marginLeft:900}} id="updateCategory" tabIndex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true" >
```

[image: output 2]

but I want to use bottom 0 and right 0 . how will these work. please help

Answer (score 0):

**Try It:**

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: 0;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
top: 100%;
transform: translateY(-100%);
```

Comment: sir it's Not working

Comment: can you share your code in jss fiddle or another ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try It:**

```
<div className="modal fade " style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end; align-items: flex-end;" id="updateCategory" tabIndex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true" >
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="margin: 0;">
        HI THERE
    </div>
</div>
```

Replace `HI THERE` by your modal content